# WPF MVVM - What is the Model comprises of

Tags: wpf, mvvm, model

Firstly, I am quite new to WPF and MVVM. I have read quite a lot regarding `Views` and `ViewModels` over the past two months, and I think I have adequate understanding on both of them. What most articles rarely cover is the `Model` part, and I find myself struggling to understand it well.

Currently, what I understand is that Models tend to be those `entities` that we know in **Entity-Relationship (ER) models** for relational databases. Once a while, I do see terms like `Services`, but I am not sure if they are `Models`.

Now, there are two questions I have in mind:

1. If I have program states, which will affect how various different `Views` present themselves, are these considered `Models`? So far, I would put them under those so-called `Services`, which are simply singletons that live only during the application lifespan. Then, I would make `ViewModels` interact with them, either by calling the `Services'` methods, or by subscribing to changes in the `Services` via `INotifyPropertyChanged`. But doing this confuses me because they don't feel like `Models`; in fact, they feel like something totally outside of MVVM.
2. My application does not use databases. In a rather odd way, I need to save my persistent information/data in XML files. So, say, if I have this `Car` model class, and my application needs to save a list of `Car` objects. Again, should I have those so-called `Services`, which would be responsible for serializing and de-serializing `Car` objects, and also to maintain that in a `List<Car>`? Then the same question comes again - is that `Service` part of the `Model`?

#### Edit

I was told my question 1 isn't clear. So let me give an example.

For example, the program has a single window with multiple `Views` at different part of the window.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <view:ViewA Grid.Column="0" />
    <view:ViewB Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

So in `ViewA`, there is a `Button` that has its Command binding. So when the button is clicked, it will cause something to run in the background (can be computational task, for example). When that something runs, the program enters into a special state. When the program enters this state, one of the `Controls` (for example, a `TextBox`) will go into disabled mode (`IsEnabled="False"`), which will temporarily not accept any inputs, until that background task finishes and that the program goes back to normal state.

So, where does this whole thing fit into the whole MVVM concept? I know this may not be a `Model` related question anymore, but when I started this thread I was thinking it most likely fits in `Model`.

Answer (score 1):

Models are not which those present the views or change the views. Models are data classes. For example say you have a View(Car.xaml) that displays the details of a car. The view may have a picture, a heading, name of the car, top speed, mileage, and so many features in common. 
You bind this view to a view model(CarViewModel.cs) where you bind the properties of the view to either a List or independent properties like string, double and all.

If you are binding the details to a list, you definitely need to define a data class for that list. For this you create a data class. Say CarData.cs.

```
public class CarData : BindableBase
{
   private string carName;
   private double mileage;

   public string CarName
   {
      get {return carName;}
      set {SetProperty(ref carName, value);}
   }
   ........
}
```

and so on..
You can define all the properties in this dataclass and reuse the same class for each view or even create  a list of cars in the viewmodel.

When the model is updated, the view will also be updated since the NotifyPropertyChanged event is triggered. 
For saving the datam you can serialize them to an xml file when required, like during the click of a button or while closing the application. 
Just serialize the list in the view model to an xml file.
I hope you got the point. If any doubts, please revert.

Comment: I am not too worried about a Car View getting data and change notifications from the Car Model. I am more concerned about the fact that I have to deal with more than one `Car`. I definitely need to keep a `List<Car>` (either `List<CarData>` or `List<CarViewModel>`) somewhere in the program. If I am not mistaken, you are suggesting that I keep this List in the ViewModel, and the ViewModel would also handle serializing/deserializing to XML file as well?

Comment: Yes of course. You could easily achieve that. Say create a listview with all the items that you deserialize from the xml file. While deserializing you create the list and keep it in viewmodel as List<car>. The listview in your view will bind to this very list. As per the list's current selected item, you can display more details of a particular car on the same view on the right or left side. You may need 1 data class just to display the list of cars, ie it contains only car name and a small desc. Another list with more details of the car. You can keep the car ID or car Name to map these 2 list

Comment: So, back to my question 1, if I have certain program state that would affect multiple `Views`, I could store them in a `singleton` class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and let the `ViewModels` of the interest `Views` subscribe to the change notifications in the `singleton` object? Then, if I do it this way, what is this `singleton` class in the MVVM structure? Part of the `ViewModel`?

Comment: Sorry. But your question is unclear to me. 
I think you’re speaking about data classes itself. You are talking about tracking the PropertyChanged event of some property in a dataclass? 

If we consider the example we were discussing. A Car data class having CarName an CarColor. You want to track CarColor.PropertyChanged from your viewmodel and update the view?

There is a main view CarView.xaml which binds to a view model class CarViewModel.cs. The view model consist of the list of cars ie ObservableCollection<CarData>. If it’s like this when list data changes, the view will be updated.

Comment: Now I got what you were asking. You want to know where that code belongs to, right?
The code will definitely go into the view model, since it is some operation that decides the behavior of the view. In MVVM, the view consists only of the xaml design and it should bind to the view model. All other operations related to the view can be included in the viewmodel itself.

Comment: Well, the biggest challenge is that this program state thing is not the business of a single `View` or `ViewModel`. It affects multiple `Views`, so it should not be in in `ViewModelA` nor `ViewModelB`. And since the program cannot have multiple such state simultaneously, I would instinctively move this to another class called `ProgramState`, which is a singleton. Therefore, since both `ViewA` and `ViewB` depends on it, their `ViewModel` (`ViewModelA` and `ViewModelB`) would have to subscribe to change events in `ProgramState`. Now, can I understand that this `ProgramState` is also a ViewModel?

Comment: Program state is definitely not a view model, since a viewmodel corresponds to each view. It can be included in a new folder say Common or ViewController or something like that. Even I have had many such files like that in my projects. Like we create a new folder for converters, since converters are not part of view or view model. It's upto you. But still I don't understand why you need a separate class for that. As per my understanding you can include the code in your main view's viewmodel.

Comment: Well, I definitely could put it into MainWindowViewModel. But I don't like ViewModels talking to one another like this. But this is purely personal preference I guess. Thanks @viashakh369

Comment: Yes. It's definitely personal. But it's that way of view model communication that keeps an MVVM based application alive. You will understand that in the long run! Good day!